# Reading/writing HDF5 file in the same order it was created

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, hdf5

I'm using HDF5 file to do a sort of "serialization" of C++ class data. Is there a way to transverse an HDF5 file visiting each dataset in the same order they were created?

I chose HDF5 because I need to access the data from outside my program as well as to be able to resume my program state.

Thanks!

Comment: But an HDF5 file is hierarchical in structure (that's what the H stands for) and won't contain information about the order in which its contents were written, unless you design the file to contain that information, either explicitly or implicitly.  If you do design the file in that way, then surely your problem is solved.

Comment: Thanks HP Mark. I understand the hierarchical structure of HDF5, so that is something that had occurred to me. I was thinking if it were possible, though, to visit elements of a _group_ (narrowed it down now) in creation order without adding extra metadata it would be nice. Looks like I will have to write out those attributes.

Comment: Might depend on the settings of the [crt_order_flags](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/RM/RM_H5P.html#Property-SetLinkCreationOrder) of a group

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me it is enough to be able to traverse the datasets in a group (and possibly its subgroups) in the same order they were created. To achieve this, (like embert said above) the groups within the file must be created using the H5P_CRT_ORDER_TRACKED | H5P_CRT_ORDER_INDEXED flags set. That is, call:

```
hid_t group_creation_plist;
group_creation_plist = H5Pcreate(H5P_GROUP_CREATE);
status = H5Pset_link_creation_order(group_creation_plist, 
                                 H5P_CRT_ORDER_TRACKED | H5P_CRT_ORDER_INDEXED);
```

And then create groups using:

```
hid_t group_id;
group_id = H5Gcreate(id_file, 
                     "/mydata", 
                     H5P_DEFAULT, 
                     group_creation_plist, 
                     H5P_DEFAULT);
```

Add all your data to your new group. To traverse the group in sorted creation order you must use the `H5Literate` function, making sure to set the `index_type` argument to `H5_INDEX_CRT_ORDER`.

```
    status = H5Literate (group_id, 
                         H5_INDEX_CRT_ORDER, // Note this argument
                         H5_ITER_INC, 
                         NULL, 
                         op_func,
                     (void *) &od);
```

It is important to start the iteration from the group, and not from root. I have not been able to make the root group maintain the order of creation of links. The solution to this is just to make a group at the root with the appropriate flags.

Using `H5Literate` is a bit tricky, specially if one wants to do recursive traversal of subgroups. A good example is found [here](http://www.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF5/examples/examples-by-api/hdf5-examples/1_8/C/H5G/h5ex_g_traverse.c) and in the [documentation](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/RM/RM_H5L.html#Link-Iterate).

Comment: How would you do it with the C++ interface?

Comment: For those who try the same thing with attributes: You're gonna footgun yourself, the `acpl_id` is ignored in `H5Acreate2`: https://portal.hdfgroup.org/display/HDF5/H5A_CREATE2